# Green Schwarz Witten (7.1.23) - Ghost decoupling

Tags: string-theory, ghosts

In the Superstring Theory book by Green Schwarz Witten, when trying to show ghosts decouple in tree level string scattering amplitudes, I find equation (7.1.23)
$$[(L_m-L_0-m+1),V_N\Delta]=0 \tag{7.1.23}$$
incorrect. Rather, by combining (7.1.21) and (7.1.22) as the book says and taking arbitrary $z$, I find
$$(L_m-L_0-m+1)\; V_N(1) \; \frac{1}{L_0-1} = V_N(1) \;\frac{1}{L_0+m-1} \; (L_m-L_0-m+1).$$
What's up with the extra $m$ appearing?